# TODO list app. Сортировка задании на каждый день

Tags: gems, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день!

Пишу TODO list.
Имеется 2 таблицы: Задания (tasks) и Расписание (schedule).
Расписание должно планироваться на каждый день с определенной сортировкой задании (приоритет задании). Т.е. хотелось, чтобы поле (к примеру, :priority) заполнялось автоматический значениями от 1 до N для каждого дня... ну и не должны повторятся (в рамках 1-го дня). Планируется, что приоритет задании можно будет править, менять местами задания и т.д.

Вопрос:

Есть ли gem для выполнения такой задачи?
Если нет gem'a, то каждый раз перед созданием/сохранением Расписания получать и проверять значения полей :priority и вручную задавать?

Comment: Не очень врубился в задачу... 
Вы хотите вручную устанавливать порядок Заданий внутри Расписания?

Comment: При добавлении нового задания надо устанавливать приоритет автоматический (если не задан в ручную) самым последним (max+1). 

Если из 5ти задании удалить 3ий, то у 4го и 5го задания приоритет должен сместиться на -1. (от 1 до 4)

Или при добавлении нового 4ым, то сдвиг +1 (т.е. в конце приоритеты должны быть 1-6). Походу снова не понятно написал :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот метод модели, который устанавливает вес записи, в соответствии с позицией id во входящем массиве. Писан для мускула, используется как обработчик к http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

```
  def self.resort(ids)
    update_all(
        ['weight = FIND_IN_SET(id, ?)', ids.join(',')],
        { :id => ids }
    )
  end
```